# String macro with trailing backslash \

Tags: macros, julia

Is it possible to pass a single trailing `\` character to a string macro?

```
macro test_str(s)
    s
end

test"\\"  # results in \\, that is two backslashes
test"\"   # does not parse ... the " is treated as escaped
```

Comment: Did you try inputting "\""? That might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @jfish003 no that will be just a the double quote character.

Comment: just curious, why not just say "backslash" in the title, like you do in the code comments? nobody will ever google for "reversed solidus" -- not in this context anyway. I didn't even remember this word existed ... I remember reading about it somewhere and promptly forgetting about it :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a work around, but you could invoke the macro directly -- as a macro rather than as a string macro

`@test_str("\\")` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to implement the functionality as part of the string macro itself. Ignoring performance, an easy way to do that is just `replace(s, "\\\\", "\\")`.

```
macro test_str(s)
    replace(s, "\\\\", "\\")
end
```

Then

```
julia> test"\\"
"\\"
```

is indeed a single backslash.